# hadoop: how to increase the limit of failed tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to run a job so that all task failures are just logged and are otherwise ignored (basically to test my input). Right now, when a task fails I get "# of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit". How do I increase the limit?

I use Hadoop 1.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the **mapred.max.map.failures.percent** and **mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent** in the mapred-site.xml to specify the failure threshold. Both are set to 0. Check the code for [JobConf.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.2.1/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.java) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

In order to set increase the limit of the MapTasks try to add following in the mapred-site.xml file.

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>{cores}</value>
</property>
```

This will make the number of MapTasks set to maximum value. In place of {cores} you should substitute the value of cores you have. Setting this value to exact value of core available is not considered good. Let me know if you have any questions.

Hope this helps.

Happy Hadooping!!!

Comment: The query is not about increasing the number of map/reduce tasks per tasktracker.